# Standard DatePicker always set empty

Tags: datetime, date, inputfield

We have some date fields in VF pages which were working fine. Suddenly some of them are not working. When user select the date from date picker, always it sets empty string to the textbox.

[image: dateGetEmptyAlways]

ATM don't know how much this relate to the issue, but I have noted that this is happening where we have more than one dateFields. Pages where they have only one date fields seems to be working as usual.

Anyone experiencing the same or any idea please?